# Get a specific value from a big JSON response

Tags: json, swift

I have this code to access travel time from the Google directions api JSON result:

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                DispatchQueue.main.sync
                    {
                        if (jsonResult.value(forKey: "status") as! String == "OK")
                        {

                            if let routes = jsonResult.value(forKey: "routes") as? NSArray
                            {

                                if let legs = routes.value(forKey: "legs") as? NSArray
                                {

                                    if let duration = legs.value(forKey: "duration_in_traffic") as? NSArray
                                    {

                                        for i in 0..<duration.count
                                        {
                                            let timeDuration = duration[i] as! NSArray

                                            if let time = timeDuration.value(forKey: "value") as? NSArray
                                            {

                                                print("Current Time: \(Int(time[0] as! NSNumber)/60) Min")

                                            }
                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }
                }
```

It works perfectly fine but it looks like really bad code. But every example i found solves it similar. Has anyone a cleaner solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a typical example of the JSON data which you are parsing?

Comment: I'm not at my pc right now but it looks like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=de I will update my question later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Swift 1.2, multiple optional bindings and boolean conditions
can be combined to a single if-statement. This helps to avoid the
"Swift if-let pyramid of doom". In your case that would be

```
if jsonResult.value(forKey: "status") as! String == "OK",
    let routes = jsonResult.value(forKey: "routes") as? NSArray,
    let legs = routes.value(forKey: "legs") as? NSArray,
    let duration = legs.value(forKey: "duration_in_traffic") as? NSArray {

    for i in 0..<duration.count {
        let timeDuration = duration[i] as! NSArray
        if let time = timeDuration.value(forKey: "value") as? NSArray {
            print("Current Time: \(Int(time[0] as! NSNumber)/60) Min")

        }
    }
}
```

and reduces the maximal nesting level by three.

There are two "forced unwraps" in your code:

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

and

```
if jsonResult.value(forKey: "status") as! String == "OK",
```

which can cause a program termination at runtime. Better use
optional casts. In the second case that would simply be

```
if jsonResult.value(forKey: "status") as? String == "OK",
```

because optionals and non-optionals can be compared.

The `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers` option
is not needed because you are not modifying the returned dictionaries
or arrays.

You are using `value(forKey:)` a lot. This is a method from the
Key-Value Coding protocol, and is often not what you need. In

```
let routes = jsonResult.value(forKey: "routes")
```

you are simply retrieving a dictionary value, that is:

```
let routes = jsonResult.object(forKey: "routes")
```

In

```
let legs = routes.value(forKey: "legs")
```

you are mapping the `routes` array to a new array `legs`. This *is*
Key-Value coding, however it can be confusing, in particular in this
case where `legs` would be an array of arrays. This makes `duration`
and `timeDuration` nested arrays as well, and is the reason why
you have to subscript `time[0]` finally. If you are interested
in the first route only, then it is easier to extract the first
element of `routes` and continue to work with that.

Generally it is preferred to use native Swift type instead of
Foundation types, e.g. `[Any]` (or a more specific type) for an array,
or `[String, Any]` for a dictionary. Compare 
[Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) from the Swift blog for more information.

Instead of

```
for i in 0..<duration.count {
    let timeDuration = duration[i]
    // ...
}
```

you can simpler write

```
for timeDuration in duration {
    // ...
}
```

Putting it all together, I would write the code like this:

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)

DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    if let jsonDict = jsonResult as? [String: Any],
        jsonDict["status"] as? String == "OK",
        let routes = jsonDict["routes"] as? [[String: Any]],
        let route = routes.first,
        let legs = route["legs"] as? [[String: Any]] {

        for leg in legs {
            if let duration = leg["duration_in_traffic"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let time = duration["value"] as? Int {
                    print("\(time / 60) Min")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note how `duration["value"]` can be conditionally cast to  an `Int`
without an intermediate `NSNumber`.

Finally you can factor the extraction of the duration data into
a separate function:

```
func durations(from directions: [String: Any]) -> [Int]? {
    guard directions["status"] as? String == "OK",
        let routes = directions["routes"] as? [[String: Any]],
        let route = routes.first,
        let legs = route["legs"] as? [[String: Any]]  else {
            return nil
    }

    return legs
        .flatMap { $0["duration_in_traffic"] as? [String: Any] }
        .flatMap { $0["value"] as? Int }
}
```

which can then be used as

```
if let directions = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any],
    let durations = durations(from: directions) {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        for time in durations {
            print("\(time / 60) Min")
        }
    }
}
```

Here `flatMap()` is used to map each "leg" to its duration,
this is essentially what you did with `value(forKey:)` in your 
original code.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer really improves my understanding in many ways!

Comment: @JonasSchafft: You are welcome – I have added some more suggestions .